# Getting the first digit after string split

Tags: python

I want to keep the `1 in 1_2` and the `14 in 14_8`. My code contains:

```
for i in columns:
    print i.split('_')
```

and I get a list that looks like this:

```
['1', '2']
['14', '8']
```

corresponding to 1_2 and 14_8. Is there a way to isolate just the first number (the 1 in the first example, and the 14 in the second) using split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer by index in the list resulting from the split:

```
for i in columns:
    print i.split('_')[0]
```